# Django Form Field Validation failed to work

Tags: python, django

Here is my form.

```
class POICreateForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(POICreateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['latitude'].widget = HiddenInput()
        self.fields['longitude'].widget = HiddenInput()
        self.fields['picture'].required = True

    class Meta:
        fields = ['name', 'vip', 'category', 'place', 'latitude', 'longitude', 'picture', 'website', 'description',
                  'phone',
                  'email']
        model = PointOfInterest

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(POICreateForm, self).clean()
        pic = cleaned_data.get('picture', None)
        if not pic:
            msg = 'You must Choose an image'
            self.add_error('picture', msg)

        return cleaned_data
```

I have given `required=True` for `picture` field and also I overridded the `clean` method. BUt both failed to show the validation error.

Here is my `view`

```
class POIFormCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    login_url = '/login/'
    model = PointOfInterest
    form_class = POICreateForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('POIs')

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        query_dict = request.POST.dict()
        super(POIFormCreateView, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)
        filtered_dict = {i: j for i, j in query_dict.items() if i.endswith('day')}

        out = PointOfInterestQuery.create_or_update_open_hours(filtered_dict)
        if out:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('POIs'))
        return HttpResponse('Error :(')
```

`template.html`

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content %}
    <script type="text/javascript">

    </script>
    <h1>New Point Of Interest</h1>

    <form role="form" method="POST" action="/poi/add/" class="post-form form-horizontal"
          enctype="multipart/form-data" name="poi_create" onsubmit="return validateForm()">{% csrf_token %}
        <div class="container row">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <!-- customizing form -->
                {{ form|crispy }}
                <!-- End of customization -->
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <div id="map"></div>
                {% include 'open_hours.html' %}
            </div>
        </div>
                    <button type="submit" id="poi-submit" class="save btn btn-default btn-primary center-block">Save
                </button>
    </form>
    <div class="modal-footer"><a href="/poi/">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-danger center-block">Cancel
        </button>
    </a></div>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Please show your view and template.

Comment: @DanielRoseman done...

Comment: I know how to do the validation through frontend. But I want django to do that job. And also I tried printing `cleaned_data` inside `clean` function. It spits out all the given form data except for `picture`, since I won't  give that data. But django fails to show error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've overridden the `post` method and avoided using the form at all. All of this logic should be in the `form_valid` method instead; that allows the CreateView to do the normal job of form validation and re-displaying the page with errors if the form is invalid, while your processing happens if the form is valid.

Note also however that you should be getting your values to populate `filtered_dict` from the form's `cleaned_data` dict, not directly from `request.POST`.

```
class POIFormCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    login_url = '/login/'
    model = PointOfInterest
    form_class = POICreateForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('POIs')

    def form_valid(self,form):
        super(POIFormCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
        filtered_dict = {i: j for i, j in self.request.POST.items() if i.endswith('day')}

        out = PointOfInterestQuery.create_or_update_open_hours(filtered_dict)
        if out:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('POIs'))
        return HttpResponse('Error :(')
```

Comment: ya, I overrided the post method, but `super(POIFormCreateView, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)` should invoke the base class's `post` method. isn't it?

Comment: Yes but you're not doing anything with the result, so there is no way for Django to display the errors. Basically it is rarely correct to override `post`, and definitely not in this case.

Comment: If I add `return` before `super` call then the upcoming code won't get executed. I want that code to be executed after the super call because `super` creates an model object and then the following code adds `value` to the newly created object. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: I can't help you if you don't listen to my advice. **That code belongs in form_valid, not post**.

Comment: you mean, `form = POICreateForm(request.POST); form.is_valid(): pass` .  A little code should helps me a lot.

Comment: No, that's not what I said. Code edited; as you see, no need to define `post` at all.

Comment: it works but I think the below code should be executed irrespective of form errors. Am i correct?